# Multilayered Grid with different Styles, Child style not firing WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

TidBit: this can only be done in XAML, no C# as I do not have access to it.

I have a dilemma where I have a grid on a form (Main Grid that controls all other controls) with a style that enables/disables content depending on the user. Now, I have added a checkbox that has a style depending on it that will hide/show a group box. My issue is that this style does not fire, although the initial setter is applied:

```
    <Style x:Key="StatusVisibility">
      <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Style.Triggers>                
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource Dsource}, Path=Value.Properties[chkbox1].Value}" Value="Y">
                <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

So in this case, the visibility would be set to hidden and I won't be able to see it, if I flipped the setters here (initially the visibility is Visible) it will show the group box.

To make things a bit more weird, this checkbox is set to a database so that if is is "Y" or "N" set the visibility:

```
<CheckBox  Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="2,0,2,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="ckbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" 
                           IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource Dsource}, Path=Value.Properties[ckbox1].Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Content = "Display ?"/>
```

Here is the group box I am trying to set:

```
<GroupBox Header="GroupBox" Name="GroupBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClipToBounds="False" Margin="2,0,2,0" Style="{StaticResource StatusVisibility}">
```

Now, where I am going with this is, are there specific rules that need to be followed where there are two grids, and the parent grids style overrides the childs grid style?

Also, if I wanted this child group box to be enabled/disabled on the fly, would I have to do anything special?

Thanks

Comment: I assume the property your attempting to bind to in your `DataTrigger` fires some sort of `INotifyPropertyChanged` event when it changes? That will be required if you want that `DataTrigger` to fire when that property changes.

Comment: @GEEF No, as I only have access to the XAML. Should I just make a bool value in the XAML, and have that control the style? But then how would I save that and then push that to the database as well?

Comment: Is there any way you can find out if the property supports INPC?

Comment: @GEEF I don't think directly, but I found this that might help trigger it:
`<cmds:CommandTrigger x:Name="SetStatusCommandCollectionTrigger" Event="OnPageLoad" CommandParameter="{StaticResource SetStatusDefaultCommandCollection}" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have code behind access, you could do it all in xaml by binding your `GroupBox.Visibility` to your `CheckBox.IsChecked` property:

```
<StackPanel>
    <GroupBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckbox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={VisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckbox" />
</StackPanel>
```

This will require you to make a VisibilityConverter (an easy google search). You can then remove your `DataTrigger`.

Comment: Works like a charm! HOWEVER, is there anyway to set the visibility from "Collapse" to "Hidden"? Or is that the Converter's responsibility?
`<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />`

Comment: Ignore that last comment, apparently you have to right your own in the C#. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Typically, that would be the converter's responsibility, and that's a very common addition to a VisibilityConverter by the way. You could pass it a parameter, "HIDDEN", then inside of your `Convert` method, check your parameter object.